# Getting back null from stored procedure through Linq

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get a return from a stored procedure from a LINQ to SQL, through a web service. However, I keep getting back a null result when I shouldn't. I am not sure what is wrong. When I try to call the stored procedure directly through Linq to SQL, I am able to successfully bind the result back to a GridView.

But when I try the following code, it doesn't work:

**Actual .aspx.cs:**

```
protected void LoginUsrBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    dt.Columns.Add("Admin");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");

    try
    {
        using (CustomWebService cws = new CustomWebService()){
            dt.Rows.Add(cws.LogInFunction("Ron", "5456"));
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Label1.Text = "Error";
    }
}
```

**Web service:**

```
  {
    DataTable dbtable = new DataTable();
    dbtable.Columns.Add("Id");
    dbtable.Columns.Add("Admin");
    dbtable.Columns.Add("Name");
    DataClassesDataContext dbcontext = new DataClassesDataContext();

    var query = (dbcontext.UserLogin(username, password)).SingleOrDefault(); 

    //returns data correctly
    if (query != null)
    {
        try
        {
                **//WHERE THE DATA DISAPPEARS:**
                dbtable.Rows.Add(query.Id, query.Admin, query.Name);
                return dbtable;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            dbtable.Rows.Add(0, 0, 0);
            return dbtable;
        }

    }
    return dbtable;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind moving your solution to an answer? It's OK to answer your own question.

Comment: I tried initially, but I do not have enough reputation to do so. Seems like I can do so now

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it by changing `(actual .aspx.cs)`

```
dt.Rows.Add(cws.LogInFunction("Ron", "5456"));
```

to:

```
dt = (cws.LoginFunction("Ron", "5456"));
```

And to also initialise the boolean Admin value before passing it through the table row with:

```
bool initializedAdmin = (query.Admin.HasValue) 
                            ? query.Admin.Value 
                            : false;
dbtable.Rows.Add(query.Id, initializedAdmin, query.Name);
```